# Not able to read Angular 2 http header Authorization token in Express

Tags: angular, express

I am making cross-domain POST call from Angular 2 application to express server and it makes a OPTIONS call first and then POST and everything works fine.

Once I add something in header like -

```
headers.append('API-TOKEN', 'xxxx');
```

It is not making POST call after OPTIONS, even I'm not able to read 'API-TOKEN' at Express (server) code. It prints undefined.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely scenario is that your pre-flight call is returning an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header that doesn't include your custom `API-TOKEN` header in the response. I would check if that is the case and add the header to the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`list of allowed headers.

Here's the [documentation for that header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers).

Answer (score 0):

Look into `cors`. Most probably you are trying to use an api which is on a different server that your page. You can enable [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) easily using this library.